# How is vue attaching v-model to child component?

Tags: vuejs3, vuetify.js

I'm currently using **vuetify 3** in my project, I separated the vuetify `v-text-field` into a different component `(Input.vue)`. The code functions completely well, but I'm confused on how the v-model is being connected to the v-text-field in **Input.vue**. We are passing the v-model as prop in Input component but we aren't connecting the `v-model` to the `text-field` in any way.

Is this behavior of **vuetify library** or **vue itself?** I normally pass my ref states to child component using `provide/injects`, but here I can't figure out how its possible.

#### Create.vue

```js
<script>
//form submit request
const form = reactive({
'name': '',
'teachers': [],
'subcategories': [],
'tags': [],
'users': [],
'fully_public': false,
'partial_public': false,
'counter': 0,
'min_time':
'publish': 0,
'publish_date':
'reattempt': 0,
'total_reattempt': ''
'image': '',
'description': **
});
</script>
<template>
    <Input 
    v-model="form.min_time" 
    label="Enter minimum time *" 
    :disabled="form.counter == 0"
    :error-messages="v$.min_time.$errors[0]?.$message || errors.min_time" />
</template>
```

#### Input.vue

```js
<script setup>
    const props = defineProps({
        label: String,
        name: String,
    });
</script>
<template>
    <v-text-field label="label" variant="outlined"></v-text-field>
</template>
```

Comment: Have you looked at the [documentation for v-model](https://vuejs.org/guide/components/v-model.html)?

Comment: Yes, I have checked

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> In `vue` **undeclared attributes** are automatically passed onto the root element of the child.

#### [By Using Fallthrough Attributes](https://vuejs.org/guide/components/attrs.html)